# Get folder path from dialog box using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: html, internet-explorer, filepicker

I am trying to open a dialog box to simply be able to choose a folder to get its path.  I am going to be using a network resource, and this site is only accessible to those IPs within our network's subnet.  I've considered using this type of element for picking a folder: `<input type="file" webkitdirectory directory>`.  However, the lack of support for IE doesn't work. The only reason I'm asking this question on here is that I've spent hours on Google trying to research this to no avail. Does anyone know of a folder picker for PHP/JavaScript? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `<input type="file"` ---> so you're talking about the end user's file system? I see no reason for php to be tagged in this...as for IE support, there's only so much you can do in regards to this issue...there simply might not be a way to have it start at any particular directory for that web browser.

Comment: Have you tried using multiple as a fallback for IE? <input type="file" directory webkitdirectory multiple>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to be compatible AND use pure JS I think you're out of luck.

I would not recommend, but it possible to to this with Java applet or Flash, but it's not really a modern approach.

Then again, if you're not uploading files or accessing the local file system, why do you need the client folder path?